# Sharepoint 2013 - Navigation Links not visible

Tags: permissions, sharepoint, links, navigation

On a Sharepoint 2013 subsite i have created a Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting. The nodes appear for each user but when hovering the mouse the contents are not visibile. The admin can view the list of the pages.
[Site Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufh4d.png)
For the links inside i have set the audience group, which does not work. I have managed to give full permissions to the user/s but still no luck. [No link appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsKl6.png)

Is anyone familiar with the permissions needed for the Navigation Links functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, the links are visable when the user has at least read rights on that site where the link is referring too. If not than the link will not show up in the navigation.